# Batch Removing File Extensions OSX

Tags: macos, file, shell, unix

i've got a folder with a lot of (~60,000) files in it.
Most of them have the extension ".html.tmp" and I need to remove the ".tmp" part in all of them.
I found some similar solutions but none worked exactly liked this. I also have only basic knowledge of the UNIX shell. OSX does not provide the "rename"-command.
I guess a shell solution would be the most convenient but any other is welcome as well.

Thanks in advance.
merriam

Comment: If you're not comfortable with the terminal, you could potentially do this without using it. Look into using the Automator app in your Mac's utilities folder.

Comment: There's also "A Better Finder Rename" http://macupdate.com/app/mac/6322/a-better-finder-rename, but you'd have to spend some money. I'm not sure if Automator lets you do exactly this.  I had to do it recently and ended up using a shell script.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this before but it made Automator crash. But now I found that altering the workflow so it doesn't need to import all of the paths in advance but rather iterates through a folder's contents seems to work just fine.

Comment: This is what the workflow looks like: http://f.cl.ly/items/1y3h000L2X033c282X0p/batchrenamescreenshot.png

Comment: check this:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
find /path/to/your/files -name '*.html.tmp' -exec sh -c 'mv -i "{}" "$(dirname "{}")/$(basename "{}" .tmp)"' \;
```

It looks a bit complicated because the simple solutions break if the filenames contain spaces or other shell metacharacters.  I've used `mv -i`, so it should ask you before overwriting any files.  I'd recommend you make a backup before trying this on your data.

Comment: The "simplest solution" actually doesn't break on filenames with spaces or other characters. See my answer for an example. If you are experiencing breakage, you probably forgot to quote the variable.

Comment: Your executed expression is also remarkably overcomplicated. Bash provides the `${var%suffix}` syntax to strip suffixes without having to do the weird `"$(dirname "{}")/$(basename "{}" .tmp)"` stuff you're doing.

Comment: The `%` syntax does so indeed, but you still have to spawn a shell to assign the file name to a variable first, and then cut the suffix on expansion. I like @chepner's solution of using `while read` instead of `-exec` to avoid the many `fork()`s and still retain the functionality.

Comment: You've already spawned a shell in your example. No need to make it as complicated as you did.

Answer (score 3):

Use a loop to iterate over the output of Daniel's call to `find`; it should be faster, as you'll cut down on the number of separate process that need to be created:

```
# Instead of calling sh, dirname, and basename for every file, use
# builtin bash commands to process the file name.
find /path/to/your/files -name '*.html.tmp' | while read fname; do
    mv "$fname" "${fname%.tmp}"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution looks like this:

```
for f in *.html.tmp; do mv "$f" "${f%.tmp}"; done
```

This does handle spaces correctly, and it doesn't require invoking a separate shell for every single file to rename (as Daniel's answer does), so it should be faster.

---

Your question states that your folder has ~60k files in it, suggesting that there are no nested subfolders that need processing. But if you find yourself in this same position but needing to recursively handle subfolders, then read on.

If you're using Bash 4.x and you're willing to turn on a shell option, then you can use the following:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.html.tmp; do mv "$f" "${f%.tmp}"; done
```

The construct `**/*.html.tmp` with the `globstar` option set means match `*.html.tmp` not just in the current directory, but also in any subdirectories, recursively.

If your version of Bash is older than 4.x, then I would recommend using chepner's solution for recursive handling. But when you don't need recursion at all, my initial answer is the simplest.

Comment: This does not recursively handle subdirectories.

Comment: @DanielRoethlisberger, the question does not mention dropping into subdirectories. Additionally, this is the safest method to handle really weird filenames (this can handle filenames containing newlines for example).